# Modify observable to interval type on the fly

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to solve a specific problem. Based on what has been emitted I'd like to convert observable from one type to another alternately.

So, for instance:

```
Observable.just(Math.random()).flatMap { item ->
 if (item > 0.5) {
convert to interval type and repat new Math.random() every specific time interval 
} else {
leave as it is
}
}
```

Right know I've came up with this naive approach of which I'm not happy.

```
if (needToRepeat) {
make Observable.interval().flatMap { prepareObservable() }
} else { prepareObservable() }

fun prepareObservable() = Observable.just(Match.random()).map { boolean = it.boolean }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Observable.just(Math.random())
        .switchMap { item ->
            if (item > 0.5) {
                Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map { Math.random() }
            } else {
                Observable.just(item)
            }
        }
```

For every `item`, if the condition is satisfied, this will create an `Observable` emitting a random `Double` every second.
With `switchMap`, every time the outer `Observable` emits a new `item`, the previous inner `Observable` is disposed, so that you always get the emissions of only the latest `Observable.

Comment: Thank you :) It's working almost like I want it to! Is there a possibility to stop updating it when item is smaller than 0.5? Sorry, Rx is not my kind of thing.

Comment: When the original Observable emits an item <= 0.5 you will get just the item, the previous interval Observable will be disposed. If you instead want to stop the interval Observable when it emits an item < 0.5, then you have to use takeUntil: `Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map { Math.random() }.takeUntil { it < 0.5 }`